# How to have neovim open a new pane in tmux without switching to it?

Tags: vim, tmux, neovim

This command allows for a new pane to open:

`:silent !tmux split-window -h<CR>`

But the problem is that my cursor switches to the new pane and I am forced to switch back. How do I turn off the switching feature?

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to. If you pass the `-d` argument then it won't switch over.

`:silent !tmux split-window -dh`